# Convert C# code to Delphi, what is the equivalent of SafeWaitHandle?

Tags: c#, delphi, interop

I am trying to convert C# project to Delphi, the C# code itself is importing functions from native dll let us name it ‘dmp.dll’ which I don’t have the signature of its native functions and I have to look at how these functions are imported in c# and try to import them in Delphi code, and I did import a lot of them and they work fine, but now I am struggling with this function (`StartLogging`). This is how they imported in C#:

```
[DllImport("dmp.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "StartLogging")]
public static extern int StartLogging(String AdapterName, 
  PLOG_RECORD_CALLBACK LogRecordCallback, 
  SafeWaitHandle StopLoggingEvent);
```

no problem about `PLOG_RECORD_CALLBACK`, but the problem is on this parameter `SafeWaitHandle`  which is class exists in `Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles` namespace. How can I port it to Delphi? What is the equivalent data type to it in Delphi?

And here is how they use it in the C# Code:

```
AutoResetEvent StopEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
```

The class `AutoResetEvent` exists in `System.Threading`
Then they call the method like this:

```
StartLogging(comboBox1.Text, CallbackProcedure, StopEvent.SafeWaitHandle);
```

Then at the last and to stop the logging they use:

```
StopEvent.Set();
```

I am really confused and I don’t know how to do this, appreciate your help.
Thanks

Comment: In this case it sounds like an event handle. Returned by CreateEvent API. Can't recall if Delphi RTL offers TEvent wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use [SyncObjs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SyncObjs) [TEvent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/vcl/SyncObjs.TEvent.html). If you create it with the `ManualReset` argument set to `False`, it should work about the same way. Just pass the `Event.Handle` (which is a THandle and is compatible with anything in the API expecting one).

I don't have a sample of using a non-manual reset event, but an example of creating a `TEvent` can be found in the  accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734644/how-to-start-stop-a-monitoring-delphi-thread-on-demand); to make it a non-manually reset (IOW, `AutoReset`), just change the second parameter to `False`.

Comment: +1 But it would be nice if you identified how to reproduce AutoResetEvent in Delphi and that SafeWaitHandle is a handle to a win 32 event. That's why I only commented.

Comment: `TLightweightEvent` is a manual reset event without a wait handle. Can't use that here. `TSimpleEvent` is identical to `TEvent`: `TSimpleEvent = class(TEvent);` The answer is `TEvent` created with `ManualReset` set to `False`. I won't post an answer because you already did, but you need to improve it in my view.

Comment: @David: Better? I'd like it to be more complete with an example of the event use, but don't have  the time right now. If you want to post a better answer, I'll remove mine afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Like David Hefferman said in a response to the approved answer: TSimpleEvent (System.SyncObjs) works the same way as the AutoResetEvent of C#.

It can be used like:

```
_WaitEvent := TSimpleEvent.Create(nil, resetmanual {boolean}, false, '', false);
_WaitEvent.SetEvent;
_WaitEvent.WaitFor;
```

If you use the manual reset, just simply use:
    _WaitEvent.ResetEvent;