# Implement override for thread Terminate method

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I am trying to override the virtual TThread::Terminate method, but am finding my override gets called only *after* the Terminated flag is set. What is the correct way to implement this?

```
TTestThrd = class(TThread)
private
    { Private declarations }

protected
    { Protected declarations }
    procedure Execute(); override;
    procedure DoTerminate(); override;

public
    { Public declarations }
end;


procedure TTestThrd.Execute();
var
    bTerminated: Boolean;
begin
    // This is the main thread loop
    try
        while (not Terminated) do
            begin
            // Sleep or use TEvent::Waitfor...
            end;
    finally
        // Terminated (or exception) so free all resources...
        bTerminated := True;        // Why is this called...
    end;
end;

procedure TTestThrd.DoTerminate();
var
    bDoTerminateCalled: Boolean;
begin
    bDoTerminateCalled := True;     // ...before this?  
    inherited;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>The [System.Classes.TThread.Terminate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Classes.TThread.Terminate) method has to be overridden if you want a method to be called before the `Terminate` property is set.</strike>
The `Terminate` method:

> Signals the thread to terminate by setting the `Terminated` property to true.

From the [System.Classes.TThread.DoTerminate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Classes.TThread.DoTerminate) documentation:

> `DoTerminate` calls the `OnTerminate` event handler, but does not terminate the thread.

Another procedure of interest that is called before the `OnTerminate` event but after the `Terminate` property is set to `True` is [System.Classes.TThread.TerminatedSet](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Classes.TThread.TerminatedSet) which is declared as <strike>`abstract`</strike> `virtual` in the `TThread` class.

---

I have no IDE with me right now but I guess that if you look in the `TThread` class, you'll find that the `OnTerminate` event handler is triggered after the `Terminate` property is set to `True`.

Comment: This looks like the answer. It appears TThread.DoTerminate is called after the TThread.Execute method has finished and it's main purpose is to call the TThread.OnTerminated event. I suspect one common use of this might be to free resources?

Comment: Note that TThread::Terminate is not declared as virtual, so can it be overridden directly? TThread::DoTerminate is declared as virtual.

Comment: @AlainD it should be like you say but also to handle exceptions occurred in the `Execute` method for what I can remember. Sorry, having no IDE at the moment I can't check

Comment: TerminatedSet is not abstract. Terminate cannot be overridden.

Comment: oops... since this is obviously a steaming pile of crap, it shouldn't be the accepted answer. Please consider to remove the accepted flag and I'll delete the answer itself. I think there's no reason to edit my answer since the other one already states what I have failed to mean. Meanwhile I'm going to [write it out a hundred times](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IIAdHEwiAy8) "*TerminatedSet is not abstract. Terminate cannot be overridden.*" Thank you! :D

Answer (score 6):

As I understand it, there is information missing from the question. It is important to read your previous question ([Alternative to sleep inside a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33960620/alternative-to-sleep-inside-a-thread)) and the comment trail.

You are trying to arrange that a call to `Terminate` signals an event that your thread is waiting on. In order for that to happen, you need to hook the call to `Terminate`. It's no good waiting for `DoTerminate` or `OnTerminate` because they execute after the thread procedure has finished.

In modern versions of Delphi you can override [`TerminatedSet`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.TerminatedSet). That's exactly what you need. It is fired from inside `Terminate`.

In older versions of Delphi, that pre-date this method, there is no way to be notified from the `Terminate` method. As I understand it, that is the key point. You wish to hook `Terminate`, and before `TerminatedSet` was added, no such hook existed.

If `TerminatedSet` is not available to you, then you will need to provide a method on your class that calls `Terminate`, and then performs whatever other actions you must perform. For example:

```
procedure TMyThread.SignalAndTerminate;
begin
  FTerminationEvent.SetEvent;
  Terminate;
end;
```