# CoInitialize error working with database inside threads

Tags: database, multithreading, delphi, delphi-7, ado

Using Delphi 7, whenever I try to do any database work inside of a thread I get this error:

> "CoInitialize has not been called"

I used a simple code containing an ADOConnection.Open inside the thread.

But the same code works fine if it's used in a form any ideas?

Comment: I can't believe the number of people still programming on Delphi 7 (or older) :(  PS: just "use" unit "ActiveX", and call CoInitialize (0)!

Comment: You know, when get used to something, you can't let it go easily, lol

Comment: @paulsm4: Would using a more recent version of Delphi prevent this particular error?

Comment: See also: [When do I need to call CoInitialize() in this scenario?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9286600/576719).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

@mjn: I'm not allowed to comment your remark in the previous answer, so I created a new answer: calling CoInitialize from the constructor is one of typical error programmers do.

Constructor is executed in a context of another thread, but you need to initialize COM on the current thread (when a thread procedure is running i.e. as part of Execute method) [see](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 thanks for answer, as far as commenting seems not be available for you.

Comment: +1 and an Amen! Threads are fragile pieces of art, you need to know what you're doing to do a thread right.

Answer (score 10):

```
procedure TYourThread.execute;
begin
  CoInitialize(nil); 
  FConnection:=TConnection.Create(...);
  try
    ThreadCode ....
  finally
    FConnection.free;
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @paulsm4 AFAIK Coinitialize has to be called in the threadcontext.

Comment: it's not about Coinitialize, but about threadcontext: http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.vcl.components.using/200911/0911093410.html

Comment: @mjn, have you tested `GetCurrentThreadId = MainThreadId` inside a subclassed `TThread.Create`? The `TThread` constructor is always executed in the context of the calling thread.

Comment: @mjn my comment about threadcontext was written because I don't agree with the comment:   "CoInitialize / CoUninitialize could be called in the thread constructor / destructor"

Comment: Why do I see many comments about @mjn but see nothing posted them?

Comment: @JerryDodge: Because mjn deleted the comments after people responded to them.

Comment: Which IMHO is a ugly practice! (deleting the comments and leave the comment thread incomplete!).

@mjn: If you're ashamed of what you said, let it stay and let the world know you're not perfect, and learn to think twice before posting a comment the next time. :)

Comment: @mjn, there was a time when the context switch happened immediately after the call `inherited Create(false)`. Before Delphi 6 that was, see [`Recreating a TThread Inside a TThread derived class`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13561939/576719) and the answer [`Which is the correct way to start a suspended thread in delphi 2007?`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4206993/576719). If `FreeOnTerminate` is true, the destructor is executed in the thread context. In principal it would have been possible to do CoInitialize/CoUninitialize in the constructor/destructor, but that would anyway be a bad practice.

Comment: @LURD: prior to D6, setting `ACreateSuspended=False` would run `Execute()` immediately, even if the constructor was still running. D6 fixed that. But it was **never** possible in any Delphi version to call `CoInitialize()` in the thread constructor and have it take effect inside of `Execute()`. `CoInitialize()` must always be called inside of `Execute()` itself in all Delphi versions.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause is that Application.Initialize; is missing or commented out in the main application DPR.